# keeeping a checkbox open in default

Tags: .net

i have a page with a checkbox. it has the related .cs code -->

```
protected void chkShowAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrlTime.ShowAllProjects = chkShowAll.Checked;
}
```

on clicking on the checkbox, a table appears. How do i keep that checkbox open by default 
so that the table appears WITH the page rather than checking on the box to access it?

Comment: the "table" here is displaying gridview data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default state of the checkbox to "Checked", and set the appropriate "table load" property at page load time.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowAll" runat="server" Checked="True" />
```

...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrlTime.ShowAllProjects = chkShowAll.Checked;
}
```

Comment: this checks the box, but the gridview doesnt display. when i uncheck it and then check it back , then it displays.
i changed the table load property to
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowAll" runat="server" Checked="True" />
removing the following property --> 
OnCheckedChanged="chkShowAll_CheckedChanged"
does that have something to do with it?

Comment: well the checkbox was set in an Update Panel. I just seperated it and put it outside the panel and used the above mentioned code.